# How to change a list of N numbers into a list of list of N+1 numbers given the constraints using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a help in converting **a list into a list of lists** such that last number of the list will break into two (non-negative integers) parts that sums to be the last number.

For example:

> Input: [6,3,11,4]

And,

> Output: [[6,3,11,4,0],[6,3,11,3,1],[6,3,11,2,2],[6,3,11,1,3],[6,3,11,0,4]]

```
list1= [6,3,11,4]
[funct(x) for x in list1 ]
```

Which function funct do I need to make?

Note: last number is 4 and it is broken into 4,0 ;

> 3,1; 2,2 ; 1,3; 0,4

Comment: I'm not seeing how you can get from `[funct(x) for x in list1 ]` to `[[6,3,11,4,0],[6,3,11,3,1],[6,3,11,2,2],[6,3,11,1,3],[6,3,11,0,4]]`? That aside, what have _you_ tried?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly using the funct syntax, but you can try something like-

```
[list1[0:-1]+[list1[-1]-i,i] for i in range(list1[-1]+1)]
```

The output is-

```
[[6, 3, 11, 4, 0],
 [6, 3, 11, 3, 1],
 [6, 3, 11, 2, 2],
 [6, 3, 11, 1, 3],
 [6, 3, 11, 0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
list1 = [6,3,11,4]
b = [list1[:-1] + [list1[-1]-i,i] for i in range(list1[-1]+1)]
# [[6, 3, 11, 4, 0], [6, 3, 11, 3, 1], [6, 3, 11, 2, 2], [6, 3, 11, 1, 3], [6, 3, 11, 0, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1= [6,3,11,4] 

def create_my_list(inp_list):

    output_list = []
    last_digit = inp_list[-1]

    for combination in range(last_digit+1):
           output_list.append(inp_list[:-1].extend([combination, last_digit-combination])

    return output_list
```

You can concatenate this into a one-liner like the other answers, but this is easier to understand